# Android: Can I change the title bar position?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I have make a custom title bar for my application but I would like to see how it looks with the title bar in the bottom part of the screen instead of top part. Is it posible to do this?

Thank you very much!

Update:

I'm trying to execute this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.headermenu);
    RelativeLayout titleBar = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.title);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    titleBar.setLayoutParams(rlp);
```

And my headermenu.xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/title" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/action_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@layout/sendbutton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/action_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/action_forward"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/action_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_forward" />
```

I get an error when the onCreate function finishes not when executing the code.

Error:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ClassCastException))    
    FrameLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 297 
    FrameLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7320 
    LinearLayout.setChildFrame(View, int, int, int, int) line: 1263 
    LinearLayout.layoutVertical() line: 1137    
    LinearLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 1051   
    LinearLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7320    
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 342  
    PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 7320   
    ViewRoot.performTraversals() line: 1162 
    ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1882  
    ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 130 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3701    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 866  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 624 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Thanks!

Comment: How have you created your custom title bar? Could you just align it to the bottom, using a RelativeLayout?

Comment: plz do research before posting question

Comment: Obviously I've done it but I didn't find any usefull answer!

Comment: are you able to make the Custom Title bar ?

Comment: Yes, the title bar works perfectly, it just gives a problem when trying to locate at the bottom of the screen!

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,You can put in your title bar in  Layout in `Bottom`

Comment: I've tried but I get an error when the onCreate function finish. I Edit my code so you can see it!

Answer (score 0):

Put titlebar  layout to bottom i will help you to solve problem